# Segmentation fault in printing string in arm

Tags: arm

```
  1 .data
  2
  3 .balign 4
  4 message1: .asciz "Enter name: "
  5
  6 .balign 4
  7 message2: .asciz "name is %s\n"
  8
  9 .balign 4
 10 scan_pattern: .asciz "%s"
 11
 12 .balign 4
 13 string_read: .space 100
 14
 15 .balign 4
 16 return: .word 0
 17
 18 .text
 19
 20 .global main
 21 main:
 22         ldr r1, address_return //load return address in r1
 23         str lr, [r1]  //store value of lr in r1
 24
 25         ldr r0, address_message1 //load message1 address in r0
 26         bl printf //call printf on r0
 27
 28         ldr r0, address_scan_pattern //load scanpattern address in r0
 29         ldr r1, address_string_read //load number_read address in r1
 30         bl scanf //call scanf
 31
 32         ldr r0, address_message2 //load message2 address in r0
 33         ldr r1, address_string_read //load address_number_read in r1
 34         ldr r1, [r1] //load value of r1 into r1
 35         bl printf //call printf
 36
 37         ldr r0, address_string_read //load address_number_read in r0
 38         ldr r0, [r0] //value of r0 in r0
 39
 40         ldr lr, address_return //load address of return in lr
 41         ldr lr, [lr] //load value of lr in lr
 42         bx lr //go to lr
 43
 44 address_message1: .word message1
 45 address_message2: .word message2
 46 address_scan_pattern: .word scan_pattern
 47 address_string_read:  .word string_read
 48 address_return: .word return
 49
 50 .global printf
 51 .global scanf
```

> It seems to read the name, but when I try to print it, it give me a segmentation fault. I don't know where it went wrong. Any hint or help is appreciated. I did allocate space to hold the string so where is the segv coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I think I see the problem.  BTW, thanks for the excellent commenting--sidebar on *every* line.  Keep it up.  It's what asm experts do.  There's no such thing as *too many comments* for assembler.

I presume that the printf on line 26 worked.  It was the printf on line 35 that failed.

The first printf only needs one pointer argument [in r0].  Notice *exactly* how you loaded r0.

The second printf needs two pointer arguments.  First arg into r0, using the same method as the first printf.

Look at how you loaded r1 for the second argument.  It should be similar to what you did for r0.

But ...  It's not.  For r1, you've got an extra indirect load on line 34.  I think if you remove it, things will work.

It's the equivalent of:

```
char *str = "Hello World";

printf("My str: %s\n",*str);  // what you did
printf("My str: %s\n",str);  // what you intended
```

Comment: I see and understand the mistake. Thank you for helping. It is working now after removing that line.

Comment: @AvinashPrabhakar You're welcome.  Someone who poses a question can "accept" an answer to their question (e.g. it's the best of all the ones given).  This gives the person who provided the answer points towards their "reputation", which eventually allows them to do more things within the site

Comment: Haha I would like nothing more than to give you as many points as you want. However my reputation is so low(1) that I am unable to up vote your answer.

Comment: @AvinashPrabhakar I just upvoted your question.  Maybe that will help.  Note that I did that for the comments I mentioned and the line numbering.  Of all the asm questions I've answered, yours has been the best phrased, most complete, so you really _deserve_ the upvote

Comment: I have 8 rep thanks to you. I will come back to this question to up vote your answer when(if) I manage to get 15 rep :)

Comment: @AvinashPrabhakar Thanks for that.  I recently answered an arm asm question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33467347/writing-a-function-in-arm-assembly-language-which-inserts-a-string-into-another/33486612#33486612  The guy wasn't as far along as you seem to be, so I gave him the notion of "arm pseudocode in C".  Fleshed out a bit more you could actually compile a program in it.  It's not a true instruction set simulator ala android studio.  But, it's more akin to a "functional simulator".  See here http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~wwt/fastsim/s0/ for one for the sparc arch.